# iOS - How to connect to flask server using flask-socketIO with out namespace?

Tags: python, ios, sockets, flask, flask-socketio

I'm building an iOS app which receive data from socket. I'm quite new to things about socket.

I use flask framework to build my server. To implement the long  poll, I find the `flask-socketIO` package. However I haven't found some useful tutorial.

I use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to conncet and send data to the server and it works fine when I test a naive python socket. Code:

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime

serverClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

HOST='127.0.0.1'
PORT=8808
BUFSIZ=1024
ADDR=(HOST, PORT)

serverClient.bind(ADDR)
serverClient.listen(5)

while True:
    print('waiting for input')
    clientSocket, addr = serverClient.accept()
    print('connect from ', addr)
    while True:
        try:
            data= clientSocket.recv(BUFSIZ)
        except:
            print(e)
            clientSocket.close()
            break
        if not data:
            break
        s='Hi,you send me :[%s] %s' %(ctime(), data.decode('utf8'))
        clientSocket.send(s.encode('utf8'))
        print([ctime()], ':', data.decode('utf8'))

clientSocket.close()
serverClient.close()
```

However, I don't know how to put it together with my flask server. This is also why I try `flask-socketIO`.

Under the instruction of the [document](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), I implement

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})
```

in my `views.py`.

Can I do without specifying the `namespace`? But without specifying a namespace, the default one is `'/'`, will it conflict with my home directory?

Answer (score 1):

Socket.IO is a specialized protocol, not a plain networking library. If you are going to use Socket.IO on your server, then you need to use a Socket.IO client on your iOS device, such as this one: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift.